# I am trying to use the simr R package to do an (observed) power analysis for a glmer model

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, statistical-power

EDIT: Pardon me, I am double-checking things. Some of these numbers may be totally incorrect.

This is unexplored territory for me, so I was hoping that somebody could confirm that I am doing this correctly. I have a multilevel model:

```
model = glmer('Y ~ A + B + (1 + A + B | group)')
```

I am interested in variable B. Using the LmerTest package, I find that fixed effect B is significant (p = .005, N = 33). I would now like to do a power analysis using the simr package. If I just do:

```
powerSim(model, fixed('B'), alpha = .05),
```

Then I get an extremely low power estimate, e.g., under 10%, which doesn't seem right. Hence, I looked more into this. I think I should instead be doing:

```
powerSim(model, compare('~ A + (1 + A + B| group)'), alpha = .05)
```

I am now starting to get reasonable looking power estimates. However, it seems to me that powerSim is comparing the two models in terms of model fit? Is looking at model fit a valid way to do a power analysis on a fixed effect? Also, if anybody knows, is LmerTest using model fit to assign significance?

Thanks

Some exploration suggests that if I do:

```
powerSim(model, compare('~ A + (1 + A | group)'), alpha = .05)
```

Then, I get extremely high power estimates, (98-100%; 100 simulations). This also doesn't seem right.

Comment: Please say why you wish to do this post-hoc power analysis. It's hard to think of cases where that might be helpful. You have found a significant result, so one might even argue that you had 100% power. You clearly did not miss a true positive result, which is what a power analysis before doing the study would have protected you from.

Comment: Hi Ed. You are correct. Post-hoc power analyses are poor form and were not used to inform data collection for our study design. We were very confident that the glmer would generate significant results, so we did not bother.

Our sample size was actually determined based on a power analysis for a correlation, which was a subtler effect and would be the limiting factor for deciding a sample size.

This purpose of this glmer post-hoc power analysis is to satisfy the editor/reviewers.

Comment: If your editor or reviewer is insisting on post-hoc power analysis, I'd recommend going to a more reputable journal.

Comment: for the power analysis, you should try gpower (https://www.psychologie.hhu.de/arbeitsgruppen/allgemeine-psychologie-und-arbeitspsychologie/gpower.html), much easier and clear--my opinion. Very popular within the social sciences at least (e.g. psychology, pol sc, econ)